# SpriteKit view shows random noise after El Capitan update

Tags: xcode, cocoa, sprite-kit, osx-elcapitan

Just updated to El Capitan, and found my SKView showing this:

[image]

To isolate the problem I tried instantiating a clean, new SKView and SKScene like this

```
 let redBox:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size:CGSizeMake(300, 300))
        redBox.position = CGPointMake(512, 384)
        redBox.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.rotateByAngle(6, duration: 2)))
        testScene.addChild(redBox)
let newSKView = SKView(frame: self.view.bounds)
self.view.addSubview(newSKView)

let testScene = SKScene(size: self.view.bounds.size)
newSKView.presentScene(testScene)

let redBox:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size:CGSizeMake(300, 300))
redBox.position = CGPointMake(512, 384)
redBox.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.rotateByAngle(6, duration: 2)))
testScene.addChild(redBox)
```

Which also renders as noise. I then tried running the exact same code in a fresh project's ViewController.viewDidLoad, which works fine.

So it must be something I'm doing elsewhere in the codebase, but I'm not sure where to look. All code is [here](https://github.com/mortenjust/droptogif).

UPDATE: This seems to happen to any visible SKView, regardless of scenes.

Comment: If the noise is not animated, it may be old data from the GPU's memory, but I don't know why it wouldn't go away...  I'll test later today on my El Capitan installation.

Comment: It's not animated, and you're right, I've seen distorted text, and even a ghost of the close, minimize, maximize traffic light there, so it is old GPU data

Comment: I just created a fresh project in Xcode 7 using Swift 2, and with the default example, I did not have any problems.  I don't see a view controller for me to put your code into, It appears that the AppDelegate.swift file handles creation of the scene.

Comment: Yeah, same here, fresh project works. In the project, the ViewController handles creating the scene. LoaderScene is a subclass of SKScene. But the main problem seems to be with /any/ SKView in this particular project. That makes it weird. Adding an SKView produces this noise. https://github.com/mortenjust/droptogif/blob/master/droptogif/ViewController.swift#L53

Comment: My main thought is that it's something in the AppDelegate.  With the `applicationWillBecomeActive`, you check if the `vc` is not `nil`.  It may be that those lines are getting slight mixed up (I don't know yet though, I've only been looking through the code for 30 minutes), and calling out of sequence. Can you still bring up the preferences drawer on the window in question? The project is currently telling me that my provisioning profiles are messed up, I may work to fix those (I just went through a lot of work getting them to work on my project, and it took a while :) so that I can run it.

Answer (score 1):

We had this happen in the office recently.  I think it may be related to a hardware/driver issue.  It happened on some Macs, but not others while using the same Xcode version and same source code.  The SKView showed the bad data for me on my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013) with NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB, but not some of the other MBP's we have.  When I dragged the application to different monitors it grabbed different bad data.

I found a fix for our situation, make sure the SKView is set to wantsLayer like:

skView?.wantsLayer = true

This can also be set in the Interface Builder by checking the "Want's Core Animation Layer".

Comment: Apple has some info on this in the Xcode 7 release notes: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/RN-Xcode-Archive/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html